# How to append child to component document

Tags: angular

When doing `document.appendChild(image_object);` in my component view an image get's added.
But when I go to other components, using my menu tab, changing routes, the picture stays there at the end of each component.

I have a module that is calling  and it seems that when I do document.append, it **appends to that module html, not the component html** I am in.

How can I access the html document for a certain component? In the component.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution.

Make a  in the component, and use document.getElementById("canvas_div").append(child_elem).

This way you will add it to that div, and not anything else.

Comment: This really is not the way to do this in Angular..